# My wordpress site is throwing faults?

Tags: plugins

0

I have recently created a Wordpress website to showcase my photography. This website uses the Memberpress plugin and users subscribe for a membership in order to see the photos. Recently my web hosting company has contacted me to let me know the site is generating faults. They are going to suspend my account if I don't fix it. I have tried optimising the site, all images have been compressed and I am using a caching plugin. I am only running 4 or 5 plugins on the site. I have tried everything but cannot work out what is causing the faults on the website. I am seeing CPU faults and spikes as well as entry processes faults.  When working on the site I am quite often receiving "Error 533 origin response error".

Any help with what may be causing these faults would be much appreciated.

These are the plugins I am currently running and I am using the divi Wordpress theme.

[image: my plugins]

This is the resource usage from last night:

[image: Resource usage]

Comment: Do you have any more detail about the faults - exact error messages and error logs from the process faults? Please edit them into the question. I'm not sure what you mean by CPU faults: processes that were killed because they hit some CPU usage limit? Since you're a photographer it could be generating different sizes for new uploaded images, which will use a lot of CPU and memory briefly, but they're one-off operations and won't be triggered by site visitors.

Comment: 533 isn't generated by WordPress as far as I know. It's generated by your host's proxy layer because the web server process on the server running WordPress crashed or was killed for exceeding process limits.

Comment: OK, it looks like this is a cPanel or CloudLinux based system and by 'faults' you do mean exceeding some limit, yes. The CPU graph is worrying: it shouldn't be stuck at 100% for any period of time. You'll need to work out what processes are running and whether this is in response to a site visitors or background operations. I'd start by SSHing into the host when it's at 100% and running `top` or similar as the root user. This is hopefully something your host can help you with.